# Synaptics Touchpad Configuration "take over" from Windows

Tags: configuration, dual-boot, touchpad

I am using Arch Linux and Windows on Dual Boot, and I managed to configure my synaptics touch pad just as I wanted using the GUI settings that are available to me on Windows, but I am completly confused about what the right values are for my settings when looking at them in synclient.

Can I actually somehow read out all these information on Windows and import them (even by writing them down by hand) to have the exact same functionality here?

Comment: Have you read the ArchWiki [page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics) about configuring a touchpad? The options are quite self-explaining.

Comment: Yes I did, but the question here is rather: Can I get that configuration file exported from Windows?

Comment: AFAIK Win stores these values somewhere in the registry, but I'm not a Windows expert and they lack documentation... So it might be easier to configure it by hand.

Comment: I don't think there is a script/tool that automatically do it, in fact it's a waste of time due to the limited options available. If you provide a list of the options under Win, we can help you "translate" them...